# In Angular JS, what is the default 'cache' value that is used when sending request with $http service?

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

I just started developing a tiny application using Angular JS. In one my Angular controllers, I've written the following piece of code:

```
$scope.createAccount = function () {

        var request = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/nxpense/account/new',
            params: {
                email: this.email,
                password: this.password,
                passwordRepeat: this.passwordRepeat
            }
        };

        var response = $http(request);
        ...
```

When a request is sent for the first time, everything's fine. However, when a same request is sent out a second time, nothing is actually sent out: I set a breakpoint in my back-end code and I checked the network activity using Chrome developer tool and I can see that no request is actually sent out.

I searched the matter in the AngularJS doc but it is only stated that the 'cache' attribute can be added to the request object to configure the cache to use.

So here's my question: what is the default value of this attribute (obviously, it would be 'true', as in my case, the previous result is returned to the controller while no request were sent out)?

Also, how can I check/change its default value? I was expecting an object like

```
$http.defaults.request
```

to exist but it doesn't...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*how can I check/change its default value?*

```
 $httpProvider.defaults.cache = true;
```

To determine the lack of call to the server, you should add exception handling to ensure any errors that occur during the request are visible:

```
 $http(request).
          success(function(data, status) {
            ...
          }).
          error(function(data, status) {
            debugger;
        });
```

**EDIT:**  To answer your other specific question:

*what is the default value of this attribute (obviously, it would be 'true', as in my case, the previous result is returned to the controller while no request were sent out)?*

If by "this attribute" you mean the `$httpProvider.defaults.cache`, the value is `undefined`.

As a side note,  it looks like you're making a non-idempotent call (creating a new email address), so if you are caching, you should not.